# In a proof of the completeness of $L^\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, banach-spaces, lp-spaces

The following is a proof of the completeness of $L^\infty$ in a lecture note by [Hunter](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~hunter/measure_theory/measure_notes_ch7.pdf):

> [image]

Here are my **questions**:

- > Can one (literally) replace $1/m$ in the *whole* proof with $\epsilon$ **and** replace $N_{j,k,m}$ with $N_{j,k}$?
- > [Added:] To be more precise, what would be **wrong** if one literally does the following change in the proof?
  >
  > - change "for every $m\in\mathbb{N}$" to "for every ${\epsilon>0}$";
  > - change $1/m$ to $\epsilon$;
  > - change $N_{j,k,m}$ to $N_{j,k}$;
  > - change the definition of $N$ to
  >     $
  >      N=\bigcup_{j,k\in\mathbb{N}}N_{j,k}
  >    $
- [Added2:] Due to the confusion of the changes above, I would like to explicitly write down the proof I meant after the above change:

  If $\{f_k\}_k$ is Cauchy in $L^\infty$ then for every $\color{blue}{\varepsilon > 0}$, there exists an $n(\varepsilon) \in \Bbb{N}$ such that 
  \begin{align}  (*)  && && 
  \left| f_j(x) - f_k(x) \right| &< \varepsilon \quad \text{for all $j,k \geq n(\varepsilon)$ and $x \in \color{blue}{N_{j,k}^c}$}
  \end{align}
  where $\color{blue}{N_{j,k}}$ is a null set.  Let 
  $$
  N = \color{blue}{\bigcup_{j,k \in \Bbb{N}} N_{j,k}}.
  $$
  Then $N$ is a null set, and for every $x \in N^c$ the sequence $\{f_k(x)\}_{k \in \Bbb{N}}$ is Cauchy in $\Bbb{R}$.  Define measurable $f:X \rightarrow \Bbb{R}$ by 
  $$
  f(x) = \lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} f_k(x) \quad \text{for $x \in N^c$}  \text{.}  
  $$
  Taking $k \rightarrow \infty$ in $(*)$, for every $\color{blue}{\varepsilon > 0}$, there exists an $n(\varepsilon) \in \Bbb{N}$ such that $$  \left| f_j(x) - f(x) \right| \leq \varepsilon \quad \text{for $j \geq n(\varepsilon)$ and $x \in N^c$}  \text{.}  $$  It follows that $f$ is essentially bounded and $f_j \rightarrow f$ in $L^\infty$ as $j \rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: I believe it would have to be $N_{j,k,\epsilon}$.

Comment: We do need the reunion of $N_{j,k,m}$ to be a null set, so if we removed $m$ and replaced it with $\epsilon$, eventually we'd choose a sequence $\epsilon_m$ converging to $0$, which is essentially the same. It's just more convenient, really.

Comment: You run into troubles with countability, since you would now take a union of sets over an interval $[0,\epsilon]$.

Answer (score 7):

It's not quite as simple as that.  The union $$ N = \bigcup_{j,k,m \in \Bbb{N}} N_{j,k,m}  $$ is a *countable* union, so properties of measures hold.  If we take the most straightforward implementation of your replacement scheme, we need $$  N = \bigcup_{\substack{j,k\in \Bbb{N} \\ 0 < \varepsilon < \varepsilon_0}} N_{j,k,\varepsilon}  $$  which is no longer a countable union.  We can avoid this by [@zuggg](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/84273/zuggg)'s method: replace $\varepsilon$ with a decreasing sequence $(\varepsilon_m)_m$.  But then we don't avoid $m$ and we need to make the extra replacement of $N_{j,k,\varepsilon}$ by $N_{j,k,\varepsilon_m}$ and write the justification of that replacement.

Edit:  The question was changed hours after it was answered.  The bulk of the above still holds, but it would apparently be useful to be more detailed in a few areas.  Let's actually write out what you say you  want with dependence on $\varepsilon$ made explicit (instead of lurking implicitly in your replacements):

> Suppose $p = \infty$ and $(f_k)_k$ is Cauchy in $L^\infty$.  Then for every $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists an $n(\varepsilon) \in \Bbb{N}$ such that \begin{align}  (*)  && && \left| f_j(x) - f_k(x) \right| &< \varepsilon \quad \text{for all $j,k \geq n(\varepsilon)$ and $x \in N_{j,k,\varepsilon}^c$}
> \end{align}
>   where $N_{j,k,\varepsilon}^c$ is a null set.  Let $$N_{\varepsilon} = \bigcup_{j,k \in \Bbb{N}} N_{j,k,\varepsilon}  \text{.}  $$  Then $N_\varepsilon$ is a null set, and for every $x \in N_\varepsilon^c$ the sequence $(f_k(x))_{k \in \Bbb{N}}$ is Cauchy in $\Bbb{R}$.  Define measurable $f_\varepsilon:X \rightarrow \Bbb{R}$ by $$f_\varepsilon(x) = \lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} f_k(x) \quad \text{for $x \in N_\varepsilon^c$}  \text{.}  $$
>   Taking $k \rightarrow \infty$ in $(*)$, for every $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists an $n(\varepsilon) \in \Bbb{N}$ such that $$  \left| f_j(x) - f_\varepsilon(x) \right| \leq \varepsilon \quad \text{for $j \geq n(\varepsilon)$ and $x \in N_\varepsilon^c$}  \text{.}  $$  It follows that $f_\varepsilon$ is essentially bounded and $f_j \rightarrow f_\varepsilon$ in $L^\infty$ as $j \rightarrow \infty$.  <strike>This proves that $L^\infty$ is complete.</strike>

The last sentence does not follow.  We have shown that the Cauchy sequence converges to some essentially bounded function for each choice of $\varepsilon$, but we have not shown that $\lim_{\varepsilon \rightarrow 0} f_\varepsilon$ is in $L^\infty$ (particularly, having finite essential supremum).  We don't even have that the various $f_\varepsilon$ have compatible domains.  ($X$ might be the union of an uncountable collection of disjoint null sets indexed by $E$, the collection of ordinals up to the first uncountable ordinal, and each $f_\varepsilon$ might be defined on only the sets indexed by $E \setminus \{e \in E \mid 0 < e < \varepsilon\}$.)  How do we know *without adding more to the proof* that

- $\lim_{\varepsilon \rightarrow 0} f_\varepsilon$ is even defined a.e., and
- $\lim_{\varepsilon \rightarrow 0} f_\varepsilon \in L^\infty$, that is, the essential supremum of $f_\varepsilon$ does not grow unboundedly, for example, as $1/\varepsilon$, as $\varepsilon \rightarrow 0$?

Well, let $\varepsilon_m \rightarrow 0$ as $m \rightarrow \infty$, ...

On the other hand, the original proof closes off the dependence on $m$ at the union defining $N$, so $N$ and $f$ are independent of $m$.  If you want to make your substitutions *and* close off the dependence on $\varepsilon$ at the union defining $N$, you must either deal with the *uncountable* union of null sets -- not impossible because they're nested -- or take a sequence of $\varepsilon$s going to zero and argue about that sequence as suggested by the line "Well, let $\varepsilon_m \rightarrow 0$ as $m \rightarrow \infty$, ..." just before this paragraph.

Comment: I'd like to add that if we were to fix $\epsilon>0$, then the part that is underlined in OP is still true, that is, we can still deduce that $f$ is essentially bounded. What is not true anymore, though, is that $\{f_k(x)\}$ is a Cauchy sequence.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I meant changing $N_{j,k,m}$ to $N_{j,k}$, not $N_{j,k,\epsilon}$.

Comment: @Jack Unfortunately, $N_{j,k}$ doesn't work because the set you need depends not only on $j$ and $k$ but also on $\varepsilon$.

Comment: @AndreasBlass: The same issue occurs in another related [question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1797419/9464). Would you elaborate why $N_{j,k}$ does not work?

Comment: @Jack Look at the line where you introduced the set that you want to call $N_{j,k}$.  A point $x$ needs to be in this set if $|f_(x)-f_k(x)|\geq\varepsilon$. So to tell whether $x$ is in this set, you need to have specific $j$, $k$, and $\varepsilon$ in mind. If you only know $j$ and $k$, you haven't completely specified what $N_{j,k}$ is supposed to be, because you'll get different sets for different values of $\varepsilon$.

Comment: @AndreasBlass: one can define $N_{j,k}$ as the set such that $|f_j(x)-f_k(x)|>\|f_j-f_k\|_{\infty}$ for $x\in N_{j,k}$.

Comment: @Jack I think your new definition of $N_{j,k}$ would work.

Comment: @Jack : Your new new condition, $|f_j -f_k| > ||f_j - f_k||_\infty$, is not the Cauchy condition.  Now you have to explain how the *actual* Cauchy condition leads to this new condition.  (It's no harder than arguing about the uncountable unions of null sets that your first version of the question seemed to entail, but you have to *actually do it*.)

Comment: @EricTowers: I define $N_{j,k}$ exactly the same way as the set $B_{m,n}$ in [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1797419/9464) related question.

Comment: Note in particular that $|f_j(x)-f_k(x)|\leq \|f_j-f_k\|_{\infty}$ for $x\in \color{blue}{{N_{j,k}^c}}$ where $N_{j,k}$ is a null set. And such $N_{j,k}$ exists by the definition of the $L^\infty$ norm.

Answer (score 1):

Enlightened by discussion in this related question:

[In Rudin's proof of the completeness of $L^\infty$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1797419/9464),

I conclude that the proof in "Added2" in OP is correct. More precisely, I rewrite it as follows.

Define for each $j,k\in\mathbb{N}$ a null set $N_{j,k}$ such that
$$
|f_j(x)-f_k(x)|>\|f_j-f_k\|_\infty\quad\textrm{for all }x\in N_{j,k}.
$$
Suppose $\{f_k\}_{k=1}^\infty$ is Cauchy in $L^\infty$. Then for every $\color{blue}{\epsilon > 0}$, there exists $n(\epsilon)\in\mathbb{N}$ such that
$$
\|f_j-f_k\|_\infty\leq\epsilon\quad\textrm{for all }j,k\geq n(\epsilon).
$$
which implies that
\begin{align}  (*)  && && 
\left| f_j(x) - f_k(x) \right| &\leq \epsilon \quad \text{for all $j,k \geq n(\epsilon)$ and $x \in \color{blue}{N_{j,k}^c}$}
\end{align}
where $\color{blue}{N_{j,k}}$ is a null set.  Let 
$$
N = \color{blue}{\bigcup_{j,k \in \Bbb{N}} N_{j,k}}.
$$
Then $N$ is a null set. Note also that
$$
N^c = \color{blue}{\bigcap_{j,k \in \Bbb{N}} N^c_{j,k}}.
$$ 
For every $x \in N^c$ the sequence $\{f_k(x)\}_{k \in \Bbb{N}}$ is Cauchy in $\Bbb{R}$.

Define a measurable function $f:X \rightarrow \Bbb{R}$ by 
$$
f(x) = \lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} f_k(x) \quad \text{for $x \in N^c$}
$$
and $f(x)=0$ for $x\in N$.
Taking $k \rightarrow \infty$ in $(*)$, for every $\color{blue}{\epsilon > 0}$, there exists an $n(\epsilon) \in \Bbb{N}$ such that $$  \left| f_j(x) - f(x) \right| \leq \epsilon \quad \text{for $j \geq n(\epsilon)$ and $x \in N^c$}  \text{.}  $$

It follows that $f$ is essentially bounded and $f_j \rightarrow f$ in $L^\infty$ as $j \rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: [This](http://www.uio.no/studier/emner/matnat/math/MAT4400/h13/undervisningsmateriale/l-infty.pdf) proof works in equivalence classes and has the same spirit as the answer here.