# In Rudin's proof of the completeness of $L^\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, banach-spaces, lp-spaces

This is closely related to a previous question:

[In a proof of the completeness of $L^\infty$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1797239/9464)

The following is a proof of completeness of $L^\infty$ by Rudin in his *Real and Complex Analysis*:

> [image]

Here are my **questions**:

> What is the use of $A_k$ in the proof? What would be wrong if one defines $E$ as merely the union of $B_{m,n}$?

---

It seems to me that if one defines $E$ as just the union of $B_{m,n}$, then $\mu(E)=0$ and  the estimate
$$
|f_n(x)-f_m(x)|\leq\|f_n-f_m\|_\infty,\quad x\in E^c
$$
implies that $\{f_n(x)\}$ is a Cauchy sequence in $\mathbb{R}$ for every $x\in E^c$ thus we can define a function
$$
f(x):=\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)\quad x\in E^c.\quad \tag{*}
$$
Now let $\epsilon>0$. Since $\{f_n\}$ is Cauchy in $L^\infty$, there exists $N>0$ such that for all $n,m\geq N$,
$$
|f_n(x)-f_m(x)|\leq \|f_n-f_m\|_\infty\leq\epsilon\quad \textrm{for all }x\in E^c\tag{**}
$$
Now, let $m\to\infty$ in $(**)$ and applying $(*)$, one has
$$
|f_n(x)-f(x)|\leq\epsilon
$$
for all $x\in E^c$ and thus 
$$\|f_n-f\|_\infty\leq \epsilon$$
which implies $\|f\|_\infty<\infty$ and
$f_n\to f$ in $L^\infty$.

> What could be wrong in the reasoning above?

Comment: Basically, in your reasoning above the very first inequality (the one before (*)) isn't necessarily true, i.e. it's not true for some $x$. The whole point of the sets $A_k$ is to eliminate those points where the value of a function is not bounded by its $L^{\infty}$-norm. Fortunately, there aren't too many of them, as it's a set of measure zero.

Comment: @zipirovich: Thanks for your comment. What is that inequality not true? Would you elaborate?

Comment: Seems to me you're exactly right. Unimportant detail: You neglected to _define_ $f(x)$ for $x\in E$. Not hard to fix...

Comment: @zipirovich ??? That inequality is true for all the $x$ for which it is asserted to be true. This is just the definition of $E$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich: You are right. One could have defined for instance $f(x)=0$ for $x\in E$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich: Oops, I didn't pay attention, sorry...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Now that I've actually read it carefully, let me try again. He throws away those $A_k$ in order to be able to say that $f$ is **bounded** on $E^c$.

Your proof appears correct as well. My guess is that the main reason for using those $A_k$ was to shorten the proof, because this way he didn't have to use any epsilons at all.

Your $f$ may not be bounded on your $E^c$, unlike Rudin's $f$ on his $E^c$. Of course, in the end it won't be a problem, because the two versions of $f$ only differ on a set of measure zero (at most on the union of those $A_k$). But you have to show that $\|f\|_{\infty}<\infty$ , which you did, while in Rudin's proof it's automatic because $f$ is bounded outside of a set of measure zero.

Comment: You're right - I didn't notice that, but the $A_k$ are not entirely superfluous.